# Rails nested model form wrong html id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a Cover model which has many Slots. I created a form following the [#196 Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [#197 Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2).
The form works fine for creation, but when I want to update a Cover (specifically a child Slot) it doesn't get updated. The problem seems to be that the html name attribute of the fields for the slot do not contain the proper ID, instead, they always seems to start at 0 for the slots and increase. Here is the relevant code:

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@cover) do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.fields_for :slots do |builder| %>
        <%= render "slot_fields", :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

_slot_fields.html.erb:

```
<div class="fields">
<p>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :width %>
    <%= f.number_field :width %>
  </div>
...
```

output html:

```
<p>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="cover_slots_attributes_0_width">Width</label>
    <input id="cover_slots_attributes_0_width" name="cover[slots_attributes][0][width]" type="number" value="50" />
  </div>
```

However the slot ID is 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: The name of the field is irrelevant; what matters is the hidden form input with the ID field that you need to pass in.

Comment: Can you paste your controller method and the html of whole form that is generated ?

Comment: nevermind, the form seems to work now, I don't know when it started working but as you pointed out, the name of the field seems to be irrelevant. How can I close the question?